# How do I not lose my RequestAttributes on new thread?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, rest, asynchronous

Using Spring 4, in a simple POST API, I am attempting to immediately return a response and continue some more processing in the background.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/somewhere")
public class SomeController {

    SomeService someService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/something")
    public ResponseModel getResponseAndDoOtherProcessing() {
        ResponseModel response = someService.getInitialResponse();
        // Async function
        someService.doOtherProcessing(response);
        return response;
    }
}
```

The first function `getInitialResponse()` would return an object to be sent back to the client but I want to do more processing using the response I sent.

So I define an Async function for my controller to call on another thread as to not wait on it for sending the response to the client (@EnableAsync is on a configurable file):

```
@Async
@Override
public void doOtherProcessing(ResponseModel) {
  // do some stuff
  ...
  // get the request attributes for some other pieces
  RequestAttributes attributes = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
  ...
}
```

But since this on another thread, it looks to lose the request attributes:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

I have searched a few things such as using `MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL` and read some debugging pieces such as [this](https://medium.com/@pranav_maniar/spring-accessing-request-scope-beans-outside-of-web-request-faad27b5ed57) but haven't had any luck.

How do I keep the scope of my request to do other processing? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try using @ControllerAdvice and define parameters to pass into Model which will be available globally

Comment: Don't... Please don't this will open a can of worms . Pass what you need to the new thread (prepare a DTO or whatever).

Comment: @M.Deinum is there a better way for the thread to inherit the first thread (request) propreties? I would rather not have to extract it prior as that will go against the current design of how we pull the attributes from a request.

Comment: No, as the thread isn't request bound don't try to shoehorn request semantics into it, it will only lead you down a slippery path.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum appreciate the response. Is there a better way of continuing processing (call other APIs, stored procedures, etc..) after main thread has returned that might meet what I am trying to do? I can continue to do more research but I though either Async or ExecutorService were the best solutions for this.